# How do I make this grid system with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, positioning

I'm trying to make the following grid:

[image]

Unfortunately it's not working for me right now. I don't know how to position containers to fill the empty space next to each other.

This is just an example to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/7m2bfx65/2/.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Container 1</div>
    <div class="col-6">Container 2<br/>Container 2<br/>Container 2</div>
    <div class="col-6">Container 3<br/>Container 3<br/>Container 3<br/>Container 3<br/>Container 3</div>
    <div class="col-6">Container 4<br/>Container 4<br/></div>
    <div class="col-6">Container 5</div>
    <div class="col-6">Container 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Container 7<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, Container 3, 5 and 6 are not positioned correctly and Container 1 and 4 have different heights.

If you know how to fix it, I really appreciate your help. I also prefer to use Bootstrap 4 Flex grid system.

Comment: What you're trying to attempt won't be possible with a simple Bootstrap grid system. You're example shows a masonry grid layout. There are multiple ways to achieve a masonry grid. One of which is to use something called [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Here is another helpful article: [Masonry Style Layout Using CSS Grid](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb)

Comment: @HunterTurner Never heard about masonry grids, but nice to know this keyword, I'll take a look at it, thank you!